# Number of orbits in a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I am confused with this concept. Consider for instance the graph:

$G$ with 
$V=\{v_1,\dots, v_{10} \}$, $E=\{(1,2), (1,5), (1,6), (2,3), (2,7), (3,4), (3,8), (4,5), (4,9), (6,7), (7,8), (8,9), (9,10), (5,10), (6,10) \}$.

This is a 3-regular graph. If I understood correctly, there's only one orbit for this graph, the one with $\{v_1,\dots, v_{10} \}$.

However, this other graph (same vertex set, also 3-regular) :

$E=\{(1,2), (1,6), (1,7), (2,3), (2,7), (3,4), (3,8), (4,5), (4,8), (5,6), (6,9), (5,9), (7,10), (8,10), (9,10)\}$

has different orbits. Which would be for this case? Is there a guideline of how to find such orbits in a generic graph?

Comment: Yes, sorry about it.

Comment: Yes, all ten vertices of your graph are in the same orbit of the automorphism group. What is it that you are confused about? **What is your question?**

Comment: For instance I think that the the orbits for the last graph are $\{1,\dots,6\}, \; \{7,8,9\} \; \{10\}$. If it's ok, I don't know how to justify it, I just felt from the drawing that these were the orbits.

Comment: You got the orbits right for the second graph. Note that any automorphism maps $v_{10}$ to itself, because $v_{10}$ is the only vertex which is not in a triangle. Next, $v_7,v_8,v_9$ are the neighbors of $v_{10}$, showing that the **set** $\{v_7,v_8,v_9\}$ is fixed by any automorphism, so it's either an orbit or a union of orbits. On the other hand, looking at the drawing, it's easy to find an automorphism which permutes those three vertices cyclically, e.g. the permutation $(1\ 3\ 5)(2\ 4\ 6)(7\ 8\ 9)(10).$ So $\{v_7,v_8,v_9\}$ is another orbit.

Comment: For a large generic graph finding the orbits would be very tedious. Maybe it's as hard as graph isomorphism. I don't know, you need an expert on complexity of graph algorithms. If you're taking an introductory course in graph theory, my guess is you're only expected to be able to find orbits for small graphs where the answer is evident from a good drawing.

Comment: I am new to graph orbits and highly interested in it! How can I interpret the values in E? Normally an edge is $e \in V \times V$ and not a numeric list?

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl : You are right, I've edited the question for clarity

Comment: Brendan McKay (and collaborators) wrote a piece of software called Nauty which calculate the orbits of a graph. See https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/. A way to understand what orbits are is to draw the graph and colour the vertices according to their orbit (as computed by Nauty).

Answer (score 3):

**Summary** : Drawing the graph is the best way I know of to find the orbits by hand. There are some computational ways, though.

**Morgan Numbers**

This may have a more mathematical name, but this is a technique from chemistry that's quite easy to do with small (non degree-regular!) examples. The algorithm is:

1. Label the vertices by degree.
2. Make a new label for each vertex from the sum of the labels of the neighbours.
3. Repeat until the number of different labels no longer changes.

To put it another way, we are forming a kind of 'extended degree' for each vertex by recursively summing the degrees of neighbours. **Note** : Naturally this does not work for degree-regular graphs!

**From the Automorphism Group**

This may be the 'very tedious' approach mentioned in the comments, but given the automorphisms of the graph, you can run through each automorphism in turn, checking if it carries one element to another and putting them in the same orbit. There may be more efficient algorithms, but I don't know of them.

**Using Signatures**

I can not resist mentioning [Signatures](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci0341823) which are a technique for producing a canonical form of a graph; particularly molecular graphs, which are vertex- and edge- labelled. While it is *technically* possible to do this on paper, it gets very tiresome for large graphs, and is probably no better than just drawing it.

For example, your second graph has the following signatures, with the orbits following each:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = [.](-[.](-[.](-[.,0](-[.,1])-[.,3])-[.,3](-[.,2]))-[.](-[.](-[.,0]-[.,1])-[.,4])-[.,4](-[.,2](-[.,1])))
[7, 8, 9] = [.](-[.](-[.](-[.,2]-[.,1](-[.,0]))-[.](-[.,3]-[.,0]))-[.](-[.,2](-[.,1])-[.,4])-[.,4](-[.,3](-[.,0])))
[10] = [.](-[.](-[.](-[.,1]-[.,2])-[.,1](-[.,4]))-[.](-[.,2](-[.,3])-[.,3](-[.,0]))-[.](-[.,4](-[.,0])-[.,0]))
```

As you can see, they are not very readable - but they do get the expected answer...

Comment: Hi @gilleain, I'm very interested in reading more about Morgan Numbers (why this works and also computational complexity), but I can't find the concept on the Internet. Could you provide some references? Thank you.

Comment: hi @llualpu see https://depth-first.com/articles/2019/01/11/extended-connectivity-fingerprints/ for a good description of the algorithm and its relation to more modern techniques in cheminformatics. Im not sure about the complexity sadly.

Comment: Thank you! And also thank you for caring about this even five years after you posted your answer :)